# How can I use ImageSliderShow pod with collectionView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, image, kingfisher

I have a collection view with four sections like shown in the picture. What I am using to load images from the server is the Kingfisher pod. what want to do when I press one of the images in the collection view is to take me to a `UIPageControl` to show the current image I have selected  and scrolling the rest of the section. I am using a pod called  ImageSliderShow to handle all of this operation. My problem is when I press an image from one of the sections on the collection view and show image and then dismiss page and when I try to select another image from different section it shows to me the same image I have selected before. It does not reload `FullScreenSlideshowViewController` automaticly.

[image: collectionview]

```
//MARK:- COLLECTION VIEW DID SELECT METHOD

func collectionViewDidSelect ( collectionView: UICollectionView,for index : Int , indexPath:IndexPath) {
    // kingfisherSources array type of KingfisherSource to add all images what I want
     for imageName in imagesNames[collectionView.tag]{
      kingfisherSources.append(KingfisherSource(urlString:"http://178.128.28.204\. (imageName.image)")!)
      }
      fullScreenController.inputs = kingfisherSources

      fullScreenController.initialPage = indexPath.item

      fullScreenController.slideshow.pageIndicator = ni
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? systemDetailsCollectionViewCell
    guard let image = cell?.dataImage else {return}
    slideshowTransitioningDelegate = ZoomAnimatedTransitioningDelegate(imageView: image ,         slideshowController: fullScreenController)

    fullScreenController.slideshow.currentPageChanged = { [weak self] page in
      if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: IndexPath(item: page, section: 0))as? systemDetailsCollectionViewCell, let imageView = cell.dataImage {
        self?.slideshowTransitioningDelegate?.referenceImageView = imageView
            }
        }

    Router.present(view: self.view, uiviewController: fullScreenController)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input for the fullScreenController is an array of imageNames and the index on which it is tapped.

Create these inputs locally and feed it to the fullScreenController. The issue here seems to be that you are keeping a variable in the view controller and not reseting it before assigning new values. Hence the old values show first.

```
kingfisherSources.removeAll()
```

should fix it. However I suggest following clean code.

```
let images = imagesNames[collectionView.tag]
let imageIndex =  indexPath.item

fullScreenController.inputs  =  images
fullScreenController.initialPage = imageIndex
```

Comment: I have added it kingfisherSources.removeAll() but does not solve the problem

Comment: I figured out something  when  I press item in the another section the data is changing  but fullScreenController does not want to delete the old data.